# Google Maps make cities clickable without using geocoder (For offline mode)

Tags: android, google-maps, offline, google-maps-api-2, google-geocoder

I need an advice if it is doable.

Currently I am using the geocoder to find the next city based on the users click on the map to set a marker on it.

My question is: Is there a possibility to access the GUI-Elements on the map and have something like an onClick for them, like the "TextView" of a city name.

To me it seems like Google Maps on Android is doing something like this. Or is it something only accessable for Google?

What are the alternatives besides of saving all city coordinates internaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it short, no it is not possible from my point of view. If you are looking for a feature like this use MapBox instead.